# "Cannot uninstall Language Pack 0 because it is not deployed" when attempting to uninstall-spsolution on sharepoint 2010 foundation

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I continue to get this error message "Cannot uninstall Language Pack 0 because it is not deployed" when running the uninstall-spsolution cmdlet.  I've attempted a number of alternate syntaxes to no avail. (tried add -language 1033 for example) I see a few other similar issues on the web, but nothing specifically addressing my issue. I know the solution exists. not sure why the Language Pack issue is arising. (by the way...i can see my solution using Sharepoint manager 2010). I've tried a number of  anyway, any help would be appreciated. thanks.

(Note: was unable to upload image of error from powershell command shell due to site restriction).

Answer (score 13):

I'm also seeing this error in one of our farms when I run the Update-SPSolution commandlet. Recently, we updated the farm with foundation and server Service Pack 1, the associated server language packs and the June Cumulative update. By chance, is this the patch level of your farm? Interestingly, I have no trouble running Update-SPSolution in another farm patched to the same level. The bottom-line is that I don't think this is limited to Uninstall-SPSolution or Update-SPSolution.

I just resolved the issue by doing the following:

1. Checked the solution store and saw that the solution I was updating was not deployed
2. I attempted to deploy the solution and saw that it was stuck in the deployment stage
3. From services.msc I stopped and restarted the SharePoint 2010 Timer service and the SharePoint 2010 Administration service. I don't normally stop and start SharePoint services from Services, but that seemed to do the trick. I also don't know whether it's necessary to recycle both of these services.
4. I then returned to the command line and was able to successfully update the solution.

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes, restarting the timer and administration service did the trick for me too

Comment: I'm glad to hear this was a helpful tip. There are times that the only resolution is to modify the state of SharePoint services outside of Central Administration. However, it's a good practice to do all that you can to stay inside of the SharePoint interfaces (web ui or the SharePoint powershell command line) for administration.

Comment: In my case restarting the timer an admin services on both servers of the farm did not help. The Update-SPSolution gave the same error further on the server I was working on. However, I was able to run Update-SPSolution on the other server without error. As far as I now remember, I had the same problem already several months ago, and at that time it was enough to open a new PowerShell prompt and run the command from there.

Answer (score 2):

While I like the answer above and I think it would work some of the time, in my case I had to remove the Errored out WSP from the solution store and then re-add it and then install/deploy it again.  After that my updates were working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I opened the manage solutions in central admin and there was an error message next to my solution. The error message was actually helpful, it directed me to solve the issue. I have added `-force` while installing the solution using power shell command then it worked fine. 
After that I deactivated and reactivated the feature just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and restarting the services was not enough for me.
Then, I solved doing:

- Retract and then Remove of the wsp from: *Central Administration–>System Settings–> Manage farm solutions.*
- Then, from Powershell, I have canceled the Features with null scope (which were preventing me to install again the package succesfully):

  Get-SPFeature | ? { $_.Scope -eq $null }

  $feature = Get-SPFeature | ? { $_.Scope -eq $null }

  $feature.Delete()
- And at the end I have installed again the wsp:

  Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath *Path*

  Install-SPSolution -Identity *Name.wsp* -WebApplication *WebApplicationPath* –GACDeployment

Then it worked :)

---

Update: I've just got this problem again, but this time there weren't features with null scope, so it has been enough just to add -Force while installing the wsp.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and after redeploying solution it's gone.